# How to Make a driving Truck by using transition in css?

Tags: html, css

The link shows code of different shapes of CSS and I think I will need rectangle and circles  to make a truck.

https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

It is code of rectangle and I have to join rectangle with circle as truck needs tires. So now I need to join all the parts and make a truck using code. Also I need to move the truck back and forth on hover.

```
#rectangle {         
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
#circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%
}
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post to ask a clear, specific question with enough detail for us to help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
    width:500px;
    margin:100px auto;
    background: black;
  }
  #truck {
    position:relative;  
    width:212px;
  }
  .rect {
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;  
    position:relative;  
  }
  .front {
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    right:0;
    background: red;
    width:60px;
    height:70px;
    
  }
  .bottom {
    width: 212px;
    background:red;
    height:7px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-1px;
    
  }
  .window{
    position:absolute;
    background: black;
    width:42px;
    height:15px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    top:18px;
    left:7px;
  }
  
  .back_tyres,.mid_tyres,.front_tyres {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:red;
    border-radius:30px;
    position:absolute;
    border:2px solid black;
    bottom:-15px;
    z-index:1;
  }
  .back_tyres  {left:10px;}
  .mid_tyres   {left:100px;}
  .front_tyres {left:165px;}
```

```html
<div id="truck">
        <div class="rect"></div>
        <div class="front">
          <div class="window"></div>
          <div class="f_hood"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="back_tyres"></div>
        <div class="mid_tyres"></div>
        <div class="front_tyres"></div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
      </div>
```

I think that's gonna be the same as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create a parent `div` class and some child `div` classes.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child4"></div>
    <div class="child5"></div>

</div>
```

Then, in you css. You can make the child classes with some circles, rectangles, whatever you need to make it look like a truck.

After that, when you are doing the animation, make sure you are applying it on the parent class, so it will move the entire truck you have created and does not affect the individual shapes (child elements).

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nosifer);

body
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
  background:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.truck
{
    margin:100px 0 0 100px;
    width:350px;
    height:210px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    
}
.truck *{ position:absolute;}
.truck #truckBack{
    display:block;
    height: 115px;
    width: 190px;
    
    -webkit-border-radius:6px 6px 0 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px 6px 0 6px;
    -o-border-radius:6px 6px 0 6px;
    -ms-border-radius:6px 6px 0 6px;
    border-radius:6px 6px 0 6px;
    
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    
    background: rgb(252,255,244); /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(252,255,244,1) 0%, rgba(223,229,215,1) 40%, rgba(179,190,173,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(252,255,244,1)), color-stop(40%,rgba(223,229,215,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(179,190,173,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(252,255,244,1) 0%,rgba(223,229,215,1) 40%,rgba(179,190,173,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(252,255,244,1) 0%,rgba(223,229,215,1) 40%,rgba(179,190,173,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(252,255,244,1) 0%,rgba(223,229,215,1) 40%,rgba(179,190,173,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(252,255,244,1) 0%,rgba(223,229,215,1) 40%,rgba(179,190,173,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
.truck #truckBack p{
    
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', cursive;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:26px;
    color:#06F;
    margin:10px 20px 10px 10px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
.truck #truckFront{
    border-bottom: 95px solid #06F;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 70px;
    margin:20px 0 0 190px;
}
.truck #truckFront::before{
    content:'';
    height:7px;
    width: 20px;
    margin:50px 0 0 15px;
    z-index:2000;
    background-color:#000;
    position:absolute;
    
    border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -o-border-radius:6px;
    -ms-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
}
.truck #truckBumper{
    height: 45px;
    width: 70px;
    background-color:#06F; 
    margin:70px 0 0 240px;
}
.truck #truckBumper::after{
    content:'';
    height: 45px;
    width: 75px;
    background-color:#06F;
    margin:-13px 0 0 -5px;
    position:absolute;
}
.truck #truckFront #truckWindow{
    border-bottom: 35px solid #000;
    border-right: 18px solid transparent;
    height:0;
    width: 57px;
    margin:5px 0 0 10px;
    z-index:1000;
    
    -webkit-border-radius:5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius:5px 0 0 0;
    -o-border-radius:5px 0 0 0;
    -ms-border-radius:5px 0 0 0;
    border-radius:5px 0 0 0;
}
.truck #truckFront #ForntBumper{
    height:18px;
    width: 30px;
    margin:77px 0 0 95px;
    z-index:1000;
    background-color:#444;
    
    border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -o-border-radius:6px;
    -ms-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    
    border:1px solid #333;
    
}
.truck #truckFront #ForntBumper::after{
    content:'';
    height:20px;
    width: 10px;
    margin:-21px 0 0 15px;
    z-index:1000;
    background-color:#CCC;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:6px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius:6px 0 0 0;
    -o-border-radius:6px 0 0 0;
    -ms-border-radius:6px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px 0 0 0;
    
    border-top:1px solid #888;
}
#rearWheel,#frontWheel
{
    width:58px;
    height:58px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#000;
    z-index:2000;
    border:1px dashed #fff;
    
    -webkit-border-radius:58px;
    -moz-border-radius:58px;
    -o-border-radius:58px;
    -ms-border-radius:58px;
    border-radius:58px;
}
#frontWheel
{
    margin:90px 0 0 235px;
}
#rearWheel
{
    margin:90px 0 0 45px;
}
#innerWhite
{
    width:36px;
    height:36px;
    -webkit-border-radius:36px;
    -moz-border-radius:36px;
    -o-border-radius:36px;
    -ms-border-radius:36px;
    border-radius:36px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#d3d3d3;
    z-index:2000;   
    margin:11px 0 0 12px;
}
#innerBlack
{
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    -webkit-border-radius:24px;
    -moz-border-radius:24px;
    -o-border-radius:24px;
    -ms-border-radius:24px;
    border-radius:24px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#000;
    z-index:2000;   
    margin:6px 0 0 6px;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Css Truck</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="truck">
            <span id="truckBack">
                <p>Loading Truck</p>
            </span>
            <span id="truckFront">
                <span id="truckWindow"></span>
                <span id="ForntBumper"></span>
            </span>
            <span id="truckBumper"></span>
            <span id="frontWheel">
                <span id="innerWhite">
                    <span id="innerBlack">
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span id="rearWheel">
                <span id="wheelEffect"></span>
                <span id="innerWhite">
                  <span id="innerBlack"></span>
                </span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I found this solution from one website you can try this one as well